# Can't exec No such file or directory

Tags: perl, system-calls

Merry Christmas to everybody. I'm having a dilemma with a perl script. In my script, I call another program with a system call, but I got this error:

Can't exec "./Classificador/svm_classify": No such file or directory at Analise_de_Sentimentos_mudanca.pl line 463.

I don't know if there is a problem in having my program in a different directory than the called program.

Another curious thing is that this script used to run normally in Ubuntu 10.10. But now I've changed to Mint 14. Is it missing some library?

Best wishes,

Thiago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this "./Classificador/svm_classify" exists ?
Check the following :

1) to go the directory where this file lays - Analise_de_Sentimentos_mudanca.pl

2) run :

```
ll Classificador/svm_classify
```

3) show us the results

Comment: Well, I executed this command, but it says that it doesn't exist. I've searched with apt-get, but i didn't find it.

Comment: apt-get is for lookup+install packages, not creating missing app-scope files :)

Answer (score 4):

The relative pathname `./Classificador/svm_classify` is interpreted relative to the user's current directory, not the directory containing the perl script. You need to do one of the following:

- The user must `cd` to the directory containing the perl script before running it.
- The perl script should call `chdir()` to set the current directory to the directory where it's stored.
- Put the absolute pathname in the script, instead of `./`.

Comment: If you choose option 2, you may find the [FindBin](http://perldoc.perl.org/FindBin.html) module useful.

Comment: It can also be used with option 3.

Comment: I've tried, but without sucess. This is strange, because in my other operational system it used to work perfectly in the way it is

Comment: My guess is something has changed in the way the script is being started.

Comment: Does it work if you try to run `./Classificador/svm_classify` by hand? Is it a script?

Comment: I've tested here by hand and it doesn't work. Even in the same directory, I've tried to execute:

Comment: Is it a script? Check for an extra character on the `#!` line, like `\r` before `\n` (use `dos2unix` to correct).

Comment: It's the joaquim's svm light. An compiled classifier. It used to work in ubuntu, but now I have mint. Can it be something in mint's bash?

Comment: What does `file svm_classify` say?

Comment: I think I got what the problem is: my ubuntu was 32 bit. Now I've installed mint 64-bit. This program might not be working because of this. What should I do? Is there any lib that makes it able to use my old 32-bit scripts? file svm_classify says the following thing: svm_learn: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, BuildID[sha1]=0x9fbe68710bf2945cddbc212947a5620aba3ded5d, not stripped

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/307064/how-to-enable-32-bit-binary-compatibility-on-linux-mint-11-x64

Comment: @Owl See http://board.issociate.de/thread/58375/question-about-using-cd-in-perl.html